# How to use Doctrine\dbal with laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I installed Doctrine\dbal dependency to Laravel with composer do I need to do anything else? Like adding to service providers? It's my first project with laravel and I'm a bit lost.

Also does laravel has some of Doctrine code within out of box? Since I used

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
return DB::connection('custom')->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableNames();
```

and it worked fine but using

```
createQueryBuilder();
```

and etc. doesn't so I assume Laravel is using doctrine\dbal partialy?

Comment: Why do you need Doctride\DBAL? Laravel uses many doctrine packages, but DBAL is optional, required only for some operations like renaming columns

Comment: Did you seen the Laravel's [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)? You don't need to use Eloquent if you don't want to.

Comment: I seen it and it turns out I got a bit confused with "SQL server" in docs... Which as it turns out stands for MSSQL. OK then it seems I don't need it after all. :D Thanks for helping me realise that.:)